# Update all time index in a TimescaleDB/PostgreSQL hypertable?

Tags: postgresql, indexing, timescaledb, hypertable

I am using an open-source time-series database named [TimescaleDB](https://www.timescale.com/) ( based on [PostgreSQL](https://www.postgresql.org/) ).

Assuming this table :

```
CREATE TABLE order (
  time                  TIMESTAMPTZ NOT NULL,
  product               text,
  price                 DOUBLE PRECISION,
  qty                   DOUBLE PRECISION 
);
```

Next,  I transform it into a hypertable with :

```
SELECT create_hypertable('order', 'time');
```

Next, insert some data (more than 5 millions rows) :

```
2020-01-01T12:23:52.1235,product1,10,1
2020-01-01T12:23:53.5496,product2,52,7
2020-01-01T12:23:55.3512,product1,23,5
[...]
```

I need then to update data to get a `time` index **minus** `1h` interval, like this :

```
2020-01-01T11:23:52.1235,product1,10,1
2020-01-01T11:23:53.5496,product2,52,7
2020-01-01T11:23:55.3512,product1,23,5
[...]
```

---

*What is the most efficient method (duration)* to alter the `time` index in this [hypertable](https://docs.timescale.com/latest/using-timescaledb/hypertables) in order to remove a `1h` interval on all data inside the `order` table ?

Comment: do you always delete data that is older than one hour or do you only want to delete that is older than 1 hour after a new data import?

Comment: I would to alter the index for the actual data only... the futures new data (which will be inserted after the correction) will have a good time index.

Answer (score 0):

not sure if partitioning is available in Timescale, that would ease the process by putting partitions based on the time-range or even date-range.

See if this is one of the options available that way you can just drop the partition based off of a range and voila!